# Databinding - databound control

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, entity-framework-4.1

I have a details view and i converted a particular field to template where i am using a drop down list. now i created another drop down list to filter the one in the details view however i get an error.

> Databinding methods such as Eval(), XPath(), and Bind() can only be
>   used in the context of a databound control.

```
                        <InsertItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList12" runat="server" DataSourceID="ddd" 
                                         DataTextField="FullName" DataValueField="Emp_id"
                                         SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id") %>' 
                                        AutoPostBack="True">
                                    </asp:DropDownList>
                        </InsertItemTemplate>
```

method to change the datasource thus enabling the filtering

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim ddl5 As DropDownList = DetailsView1.FindControl("DropDownList12")
    ddl5.DataSourceID = ""
    ddl5.DataSource = FilterDataSource
    ddl5.DataBind()
End Sub
```

If i take off

```
  **SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Employee_Personal_InfoEmp_id") %>'**
```

the filter would work. Any workaround to this? i need the binding. thanks

Answer (score 0):

inorder to get this to work the way you want, you're going to need to find the control in the itemDataBound event, and then create an event handler to assign to the address of the drop down box ctl in the itemdataBound event.